# Who was the old human woman in Niima Outpost?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

In *The Force Awakens*, while Rey was scrubbing her salvage in Niima Outpost, she took a serious glance at an old human lady next to her. Rey suddenly became deeply thoughtful and it looked like she was about to say something to the fellow salvage cleaner, as one of Plutt's scumbags interrupted her.

[image]

Who was this old woman? Did she have a meaning to Rey? The movie doesn't tell much, but maybe there is something in other sources, as usual.

Comment: I assume she was thinking..."Is that me in 40 years?"

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't _Dennis_? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvKIWjnEPNY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) describes her as an 'old woman'.

> EXT. NIIMA OUTPOST - CLEANING TABLE - DAY
>
> TIGHT ON REY'S HANDS as she SCRUBS CLEAN her day's salvage. Rey
> glances up: she looks at an old woman, also cleaning some salvage.
>
> Rey watches her, gets lost in the simple moment. A small, passing
> alien UNDERLING barks something to her in another language. She
> returns to work.

She doesn't appear to be anyone special, just an elderly scavenger (to hammer home where Rey's life is heading if she doesn't embrace her destiny).

---

As to why Rey was looking thoughtful, this was actually because she was observing a mother and her child in the original cut. The shot didn't make it into the theatrical version of the film (although her reaction-shot did) but you can see the scene in its entirety in the [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)).

> *Glancing up from her work, her gaze happened to fall outside the tent.
> The biped whose movements had caught her eye was human. A woman, clad
> in wrappings of deep maroon that shaded to purple, a band of turquoise
> makeup across her eyes and forefingers indicating her clan. Standing
> on a ship’s open ramp, she surveyed her surroundings. A moment later a
> similarly clad and decorated boy appeared and moved to join her. **A
> domestic exchange ensued, during which the adult did something to the
> child’s hair. Returning to her work, Rey was only partially aware that
> the brush she was using on a narrow piece of salvaged electronics had
> begun to imitate the same caressing, grooming movement of the woman’s
> fingers.***
>
> *Coming up beside her, one of Unkar Plutt’s assistants barked
> at her and gestured in her direction with his staff, implying it would
> be in her best interests to focus on her work and not allow herself to
> be distracted. Without another glance in the direction of the mother
> and child, Rey returned to her own work.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: She's nothing, no one... But not to *me*.